# RedisSearch query for selecting rooms based on specific average AfterDiscountAmount between two dates and filtering blocked days

Tags: redis, redisearch

I have an issue when I want to write a query against nested arrays on `RedisSearch`.

I have stored many keys; a sample of those values is JSON:

```
{
  "Id": "100000",
  "RoomName": "Electronics",
  
  "DailySpecs": [
    {
      "RoomId": "100000",
      "DateTime": "2023-05-26T00:00:00+03:30",
      "DateTimeLong": 1685046600,
      "BeforeDiscountAmount": 19586000,
      "AfterDiscountAmount": 7834400,
      "IsInstantDay": 0,
      "IsBlocked": "0"
    },
    {
      "RoomId": "100000",
      "DateTime": "2023-05-27T00:00:00+03:30",
      "DateTimeLong": 1685133000,
      "BeforeDiscountAmount": 149579000,
      "AfterDiscountAmount": 74789500,
      "IsInstantDay": 1,
      "IsBlocked": "0"
    },
    {
      "RoomId": "100000",
      "DateTime": "2023-05-28T00:00:00+03:30",
      "DateTimeLong": 1685219400,
      "BeforeDiscountAmount": 13934000,
      "AfterDiscountAmount": 9753800,
      "IsInstantDay": 0,
      "IsBlocked": "0"
    },
    {
      "RoomId": "100000",
      "DateTime": "2023-05-29T00:00:00+03:30",
      "DateTimeLong": 1685305800,
      "BeforeDiscountAmount": 176372000,
      "AfterDiscountAmount": 141097600,
      "IsInstantDay": 0,
      "IsBlocked": "0"
    },
    {
      "RoomId": "100000",
      "DateTime": "2023-05-30T00:00:00+03:30",
      "DateTimeLong": 1685392200,
      "BeforeDiscountAmount": 22503000,
      "AfterDiscountAmount": 20252700,
      "IsInstantDay": 0,
      "IsBlocked": "0"
    },
    {
      "RoomId": "100000",
      "DateTime": "2023-05-31T00:00:00+03:30",
      "DateTimeLong": 1685478600,
      "BeforeDiscountAmount": 78353000,
      "AfterDiscountAmount": 31341200,
      "IsInstantDay": 0,
      "IsBlocked": "0"
    },
    {
      "RoomId": "100000",
      "DateTime": "2023-06-01T00:00:00+03:30",
      "DateTimeLong": 1685565000,
      "BeforeDiscountAmount": 195242000,
      "AfterDiscountAmount": 136669400,
      "IsInstantDay": 1,
      "IsBlocked": "0"
    },
    {
      "RoomId": "100000",
      "DateTime": "2023-06-02T00:00:00+03:30",
      "DateTimeLong": 1685651400,
      "BeforeDiscountAmount": 72294000,
      "AfterDiscountAmount": 50605800,
      "IsInstantDay": 0,
      "IsBlocked": "0"
    },
    {
      "RoomId": "100000",
      "DateTime": "2023-06-03T00:00:00+03:30",
      "DateTimeLong": 1685737800,
      "BeforeDiscountAmount": 164136000,
      "AfterDiscountAmount": 131308800,
      "IsInstantDay": 0,
      "IsBlocked": "0"
    },
    {
      "RoomId": "100000",
      "DateTime": "2023-06-04T00:00:00+03:30",
      "DateTimeLong": 1685824200,
      "BeforeDiscountAmount": 111217000,
      "AfterDiscountAmount": 77851900,
      "IsInstantDay": 0,
      "IsBlocked": "0"
    },
    {
      "RoomId": "100000",
      "DateTime": "2023-06-05T00:00:00+03:30",
      "DateTimeLong": 1685910600,
      "BeforeDiscountAmount": 123948000,
      "AfterDiscountAmount": 99158400,
      "IsInstantDay": 0,
      "IsBlocked": "1"
    },
    {
      "RoomId": "100000",
      "DateTime": "2023-06-06T00:00:00+03:30",
      "DateTimeLong": 1685997000,
      "BeforeDiscountAmount": 77782000,
      "AfterDiscountAmount": 70003800,
      "IsInstantDay": 1,
      "IsBlocked": "0"
    },
    {
      "RoomId": "100000",
      "DateTime": "2023-06-07T00:00:00+03:30",
      "DateTimeLong": 1686083400,
      "BeforeDiscountAmount": 101413000,
      "AfterDiscountAmount": 60847800,
      "IsInstantDay": 1,
      "IsBlocked": "0"
    },
    {
      "RoomId": "100000",
      "DateTime": "2023-06-08T00:00:00+03:30",
      "DateTimeLong": 1686169800,
      "BeforeDiscountAmount": 1545000,
      "AfterDiscountAmount": 927000,
      "IsInstantDay": 0,
      "IsBlocked": "1"
    },
    {
      "RoomId": "100000",
      "DateTime": "2023-06-09T00:00:00+03:30",
      "DateTimeLong": 1686256200,
      "BeforeDiscountAmount": 64861000,
      "AfterDiscountAmount": 58374900,
      "IsInstantDay": 1,
      "IsBlocked": "0"
    },
    {
      "RoomId": "100000",
      "DateTime": "2023-06-10T00:00:00+03:30",
      "DateTimeLong": 1686342600,
      "BeforeDiscountAmount": 139339000,
      "AfterDiscountAmount": 97537300,
      "IsInstantDay": 0,
      "IsBlocked": "1"
    },
    {
      "RoomId": "100000",
      "DateTime": "2023-06-11T00:00:00+03:30",
      "DateTimeLong": 1686429000,
      "BeforeDiscountAmount": 109163000,
      "AfterDiscountAmount": 54581500,
      "IsInstantDay": 0,
      "IsBlocked": "0"
    },
    {
      "RoomId": "100000",
      "DateTime": "2023-06-12T00:00:00+03:30",
      "DateTimeLong": 1686515400,
      "BeforeDiscountAmount": 172948000,
      "AfterDiscountAmount": 121063600.0,
      "IsInstantDay": 1,
      "IsBlocked": "0"
    },
    {
      "RoomId": "100000",
      "DateTime": "2023-06-13T00:00:00+03:30",
      "DateTimeLong": 1686601800,
      "BeforeDiscountAmount": 92064000,
      "AfterDiscountAmount": 73651200,
      "IsInstantDay": 1,
      "IsBlocked": "0"
    },
    {
      "RoomId": "100000",
      "DateTime": "2023-06-14T00:00:00+03:30",
      "DateTimeLong": 1686688200,
      "BeforeDiscountAmount": 50504000,
      "AfterDiscountAmount": 20201600,
      "IsInstantDay": 0,
      "IsBlocked": "0"
    },
    {
      "RoomId": "100000",
      "DateTime": "2023-06-15T00:00:00+03:30",
      "DateTimeLong": 1686774600,
      "BeforeDiscountAmount": 95269000,
      "AfterDiscountAmount": 38107600,
      "IsInstantDay": 1,
      "IsBlocked": "0"
    },
    {
      "RoomId": "100000",
      "DateTime": "2023-06-16T00:00:00+03:30",
      "DateTimeLong": 1686861000,
      "BeforeDiscountAmount": 138475000,
      "AfterDiscountAmount": 55390000,
      "IsInstantDay": 0,
      "IsBlocked": "0"
    }]
```

In the above JSON,  the `DailySpecs` represents the daily specifications of each room, including blocked or unblocked, AfterDiscountAmount(Price after discount), and the DateTime.
I want to select rooms with no block days(IsBlocked=="0") and have a specific average for `AfterDiscountAmount` between two specific days.

Created index information is :

```
1) "index_name"
2) "roomBox-idx"
3) "index_options"
4) (empty list or set)
5) "index_definition"
6) 1) "key_type"
   2) "JSON"
   3) "prefixes"
   4) 1) "RoomBox"
   5) "default_score"
   6) "1"
7) "attributes"
8) 1) 1) "identifier"
      2) "$.RoomName"
      3) "attribute"
      4) "RoomName"
      5) "type"
      6) "TEXT"
      7) "WEIGHT"
      8) "1"
   
   2) 1) "identifier"
      2) "$.DailySpecs[*].RoomId"
      3) "attribute"
      4) "DailySpecs_RoomId"
      5) "type"
      6) "TAG"
      7) "SEPARATOR"
      8) "|"
      9) "SORTABLE"
      10) "UNF"
   3) 1) "identifier"
      2) "$.DailySpecs[*].DateTimeLong"
      3) "attribute"
      4) "DailySpecs_DateTimeLong"
      5) "type"
      6) "NUMERIC"
      7) "SORTABLE"
      8) "UNF"
   4) 1) "identifier"
      2) "$.DailySpecs[*].AfterDiscountAmount"
      3) "attribute"
      4) "DailySpecs_AfterDiscountAmount"
      5) "type"
      6) "NUMERIC"
      7) "SORTABLE"
      8) "UNF"
   5) 1) "identifier"
      2) "$.DailySpecs[*].IsBlocked"
      3) "attribute"
      4) "DailySpecs_IsBlocked"
      5) "type"
      6) "TAG"
      7) "SEPARATOR"
      8) "|"
      9) "SORTABLE"
      10) "UNF"
```

I've written the following query but seems it just consider the first element of nested array in query:

```
"FT.AGGREGATE" "roomBox-idx" "@DailySpecs_IsBlocked:{0} @DailySpecs_DateTimeLong:[1685046600 inf] @DailySpecs_DateTimeLong:[-inf (1685392200] " "GROUPBY" "1" "@DailySpecs_RoomId" "REDUCE" "COUNT" "0" "AS" "COUNT" "REDUCE" "AVG" "1" "@DailySpecs_AfterDiscountAmount" "AS" "ADA_AVG" "FILTER" " @ADA_AVG <= 900000000 && @ADA_AVG >= 0" "LIMIT" "0" "10"
```

Where I made a mistake?

Thanks.

Comment: what is the output of the query?

Comment: It just returns the `AfterDiscountAmount` of the first value of the array instead of the average.

Comment: Can you try running it with `FT.PROFILE` if you can? Can you run it with `TIMEOUT 0` to check if the problem is a timeout?

Comment: Coming back to this, I think the problem is a misuse of the multi-value indexing. I believe that in your case you better index each daily spec as a individual document

Comment: Thanks, I did it, but I have to store a lot of useless data.